# CompletableFutures: processing of CompletableFuture chains in parallel

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I am designing an asynchronous call with `CompletableFuture`s. This is a batch call, where I need to process several entities at once. At the end of the call I have to collect information about the status of the processing of every item.

As the input I have an array of ids of those entities. This is a complex entity, I have to place several DAO calls in order to compile an entity into an object. Each of DAO methods return `CompletableFuture<PartX>`.

I am chaining those DAO calls because if one of the pieces does not exist I won't be able to construct a whole object. Here is how my snippet looks like:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class CfChainsAllOfTest {

    private DAO dao = new DAO();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> resultPrintingCf = new CfChainsAllOfTest().fetchAllInParallelAndCollect(Lists.newArrayList(1l, 2l, 3l)).thenAccept(results -> {
            System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + results);
        });
        resultPrintingCf.join();
    }

    private CompletableFuture<List<Item>> fetchAllInParallelAndCollect(List<Long> ids) {
        List<CompletableFuture<Item>> cfs = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (Long id : ids) {
            // I want this to be an instant non-blocking operation
            cfs.add(fetchSingle(id));
            System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + "After completable future was added to the list, id=" + id);
        }
        return waitAllOfAndCollect(cfs);
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Item> fetchSingle(Long id) {
        return getPartCAndSetOnItem(new Item(id)).thenCompose(this::getPartBAndSetOnItem).thenCompose(this::getPartAAndSetOnItem);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Item> getPartCAndSetOnItem(Item item) {
        return dao.getPartC(item.getId()).thenCompose(partC -> {
            CompletableFuture<Item> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
            item.setPartC(partC);
            cf.complete(item);
            return cf;
        });
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Item> getPartBAndSetOnItem(Item item) {
        return dao.getPartB(item.getId()).thenCompose(partB -> {
            CompletableFuture<Item> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
            item.setPartB(partB);
            cf.complete(item);
            return cf;
        });
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Item> getPartAAndSetOnItem(Item item) {
        return dao.getPartA(item.getId()).thenCompose(partA -> {
            CompletableFuture<Item> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
            item.setPartA(partA);
            cf.complete(item);
            return cf;
        });
    }

    private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> waitAllOfAndCollect(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
        return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v -> futures.stream().map(future -> future.join()).collect(Collectors.<T> toList()));
    }

    static class DAO {

        public CompletableFuture<PartC> getPartC(Long id) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + "Fetching Part C from database for id=" + id);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + "Part C fetched from db for id=" + id);
                return new PartC();
            });
        }

        public CompletableFuture<PartB> getPartB(Long id) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + "Fetching Part B from database for id=" + id);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + "Part B fetched from db for id=" + id);
                return new PartB();
            });
        }

        public CompletableFuture<PartA> getPartA(Long id) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + "Fetching Part A from database for id=" + id);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]" + "Part A fetched from db  for id=" + id);
                return new PartA();
            });
        }

    }

    static class Item {

        private final Long id;

        private PartA partA;
        private PartB partB;
        private PartC partC;

        public Item(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public PartA getPartA() {
            return partA;
        }

        public void setPartA(PartA partA) {
            this.partA = partA;
        }

        public PartB getPartB() {
            return partB;
        }

        public void setPartB(PartB partB) {
            this.partB = partB;
        }

        public PartC getPartC() {
            return partC;
        }

        public void setPartC(PartC partC) {
            this.partC = partC;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [id=" + id + ", partA=" + partA + ", partB=" + partB + ", partC=" + partC + "]";
        }

    }

    static class PartA {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Part A";
        }

    }

    static class PartB {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Part B";
        }
    }

    static class PartC {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Part C";
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that processing for each item is not really done in parallel because of the chaining. It looks like chaining of `CompletableFuture`s is a blocking call. I would expect the chain of CFs to return variable of `CompletableFuture<Whole>` immediately and only after that start computing the value.

That said, what would be the best way to achieve such behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the chained DAO calls accept the previous results? Also, `CompletableFuture` doesn't have a method `then()`. What type is the DAO actually returning? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that `thenCompose` will be run on the thread that completes the future. If the future is already completed at the point of calling; it will run on the thread that calls `thenCompose`. This may well be your problem if you are not seeing parallelism here. Call `thenComposeAsync`.

Comment: When I have created this sample I see that it works in parallel as expected, but in my junit test when I test my other code that is based on the same approach, I do not see parallelism =( 
Could it be related to the fact that I am mocking my completable futures with Mockito? I do complete them.

Comment: Just another note: you might benefit from batch-fetching at DAO level instead: if each DAO accepted the list of id's (typically to perform an `in (…)` query), you would perform much less queries. It could probably be reduced to 3 queries in total instead of 3 per item. This kind of optimisation is probably much more effective than parallelism – I did it recently on one of our projects and got an amazing speed boost (like 20+ times faster).

Comment: It's a legacy DAO, ain't nobody touching it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this method:

```
private CompletableFuture<Item> fetchSingle(Long id) {
    return getPartCAndSetOnItem(new Item(id)).thenCompose(this::getPartBAndSetOnItem).thenCompose(this::getPartAAndSetOnItem);
}
```

Basically you are telling: *get part C, then get part B, then get part A.*

Instead, you should call the 3 methods, then merge the results – though that might not be necessary here due to the way you just store the result on the `Item` (pay attention to the Java memory model here, as your `Item` is not synchronized here: it might not work properly for more complex examples).

So, basically:

```
private CompletableFuture<Item> fetchSingle(Long id) {
    Item result = new Item(id);
    CompletableFuture<?> c = getPartCAndSetOnItem(result);
    CompletableFuture<?> b = getPartBAndSetOnItem(result);
    CompletableFuture<?> a = getPartAAndSetOnItem(result);
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b, c).thenApply(__ -> result);
}
```

Of course, the drawback is that you perform all 3 calls even if one fails, but you cannot have your cake and eat it…

As a side note, your `getPartXAndSetOnItem()` methods can be simplified to

```
public CompletableFuture<Item> getPartXAndSetOnItem(Item item) {
    return dao.getPartX(item.getId()).thenApply(partX -> {
        item.setPartX(partX);
        return item;
    });
}
```

or, considering we don't care about the actual result type in `fetchSingle()`:

```
public CompletableFuture<?> getPartXAndSetOnItem(Item item) {
    return dao.getPartX(item.getId()).thenRun(item::setPartX);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I want to avoid, if one of the parts is not there, it doesn't make sense to fetch the rest.

Comment: And why do you say that fetchSIngle() is the problem? Shouldn't it be non-blocking after all?

Comment: Well, you have contradicting requirements: on the one side, you want to run everything in parallel, and on the other side, you want to check whether the previous call succeeded before performing the next one…

Comment: `fetchSingle()` is non-blocking, but your chain of calls makes them sequential. It does not prevent working on the other items at the same time though.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming that. But somehow in my JUnit test I do not see parallel behaviour.

Comment: Is that a bad thing to chain the calls as I am doing and on each step of the way apply changes to the entity I am building? Is that an anti-pattern?

Comment: Chaining the calls is ok, but the problem with applying the changes like that is that one thread might not see the changes of the other threads, resulting in inconsistent state. I am not an expert but I think it is better to apply all the changes at once at the end, or in `thenCombine()` calls, than in parallel without synchronization.

Comment: The thing is that the output of one CF is the input for the other, it's not like they are changing an outside entity.